# All the Signs point to the Second Prime...Figure out the Missing Digits

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers

$Given$

The six Interrelated Equations A, B, C, D, E, F

All equal to 3.

Allowed Digits.. 1 to 9.

All the missing 9 are distinct...9?s...9 Different Digits

Fillin all the digits that satisfy all these Relations.

[image: Six Ernst.with 3]

Comment: On the ordering of operations, do we assume multiplication and division are performed before addition and subtraction? Also, is the bottom row and rightmost column "(?-?)+?" or "?-(?+?)"

Comment: Is there a unique solution and are all the values unique?

Comment: Order of operations ..A, B, C ...3 Horizontal. D, E, F...3 Vertical...Bottom right 4 squares...blank..like other black cells.

Comment: Based on what I could figure out, it is unique

Comment: Just to clarify, what would be the value of $3+3 \times 2$?

Comment: Order of operations as given would be..3+3=6,,,6x2=12....follow the operations in the order given in both horizontal and vertical sets.

Comment: What are these puzzles called? I've seen them called Cross Sums (for example, in the Puzzle Page app), but apparently that name is used to describe Kankuro puzzles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution, which is unique given the constraints.

> ```
>  1 * 9 - 6  = 3
>  *   -   -
>  7 + 8 / 5  = 3
>  -   *   +
>  4 - 3 + 2  = 3
>  =   =   =
>  3   3   3
> ```

Proof

> The digit in the bottom middle must be either $1$ or $3$ since the product of the second column is $3$.
>  If it is $1$ then the other entries in the bottom row are either $2,2$ or $1,3$ but we are not allowed to repeat digits. Hence, it must be $3$.
>  This means the other digits in the bottom row will be $2,4$ or $1,5$.
>  Now, suppose $1$ is on the left in the bottom row. This means the first product on the left-hand column is $4$ which cannot be constructed without repeating digits.
>  Alternatively, suppose $5$ is on the left in the bottom. Then the other digits in the left-hand column must be $2$ and $4$ since $1$ has already been used. This means the last entry in the second row is at least $6$ which is not permissible since the sum cannot be greater than $17$.
>  Hence, the other two entries in the bottom row must be $2$ and $4$.
>  Now suppose $2$ is on the left. This means that the other entries in the left-hand column are $1$ and $5$ which forces the last entry in the second row to be at least $6$, not allowed. Hence the bottom row must be $4,3,2$.
>  From there, we know that the other entries in the left-hand column are $1$ and $7$.
>  This means the last entry in the second row must be $5$ since it is the only option available that could possibly work. Hence the sum of the first two digits in the second row is $15$ which makes the first entry $7$ and the second $8$.
>  This means the top left-hand corner must be $1$ and we are left with $9$ and $6$ to complete the grid.

Comment: This morning, my mind is not sharp..forgot to mention that there are no repeating digits...will edit to reflect that..

Comment: Got it !!...sorry about all those edits

Comment: @Uvc No, that's fine. Nice puzzle!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

> ```
>  1 * 3 - 0  = 3
>  *   -   -
>  3 + 0 / 1  = 3
>  -   *   +
>  0 - 1 + 4  = 3
>  =   =   =
>  3   3   3
> ```

Comment: I forgot to mention..that only 1 to 9 are allowed...will edit it now..sorry about that